# Visual Basic .NET: how to create a task from a method with parameters

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I have a sub method with a parameter:

```
Public Sub mysub(ByVal x As Object)
    [...]
End Sub
```

To launch it as a thread, I do simply:

```
Dim x1 as String = "hello"
mythread = New Thread(AddressOf mysub)
mythread.Start(x1)
```

I would transform `mysub` in an `async` function. The online tutorials ([this one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async-vbnet) for example) are only for methods without parameters.

I tried with:

```
Dim mytask As Task
Dim x1 as String = "hello"
mytask = New Task(Me.mysub, x1)
mytast.Start()
```

but I get the error:

> Error BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'x' of 'Public Sub
>   mysub(x As Object)'

Comment: If you use .NET 4.0 or higher you can use lambdas: `New Task(Sub() Me.mysub(x1))`

Comment: That's it! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Using a sub **`method`** will cause code to continue running in paralell, both main and sub code. Notice this might lead to race-conditions ([see here](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Beware-of-Async-Sub-or-Void)), and also you won't be able to 'fully' take advantage of the async / await convenient programming. This is exactly the same scenario as the multi-thread app you suggested at the beginning.

In VB you need to make a `lambda` custom sub for calling your code, then you can pass any parameter:

```
    Dim t As Task
    t = New Task(Sub() mysub(param))

    Public Sub mysub(ByVal param As ParamObject)
        [...]
    End Sub
```

However, for completeness of the answer, let's consider additionally using a **`function`** as well. All functions return some information and by using the `await` keyword it will force the code execution to pause until the result is ready.

Here in VB you need to define a lambda custom function including return type. Then you can call your function including any needed parameters.

```
    Dim t As Task(Of RetObject)
    t = Task.Run(Function() As RetObject
                     Return myfunction(param)
                 End Function)
    Return Await t

    Public Function myfunction(ByVal param As ParamObject) As RetObject
        [...]
    End Function
```

What you are doing here is an `async` wrapper function for sync code. This is discouraged for many reasons ([see here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)). It's always recommended to write code from scratch which takes `async-await` behavior from the basement.