# How do you pass a parameter to a task (Async Multithreading)?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, async-await

I think I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964024/visual-basic-net-how-to-create-a-task-from-a-method-with-parameters), but it's all going a bit wrong - I just seem to pass the number 5 to every thread!

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the parameter value be fixed once the sub has been called?

```
Public Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ji As Integer, tasks As New List(Of Task)()

    For ji = 0 To 4
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() findPageCount(ji)))
    Next

    Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
end sub

Sub findPageCount(ByVal iAmThread As Integer)

    Debug.Print("I am thread " & iAmThread)

    '...lots more stuff...

end sub
```

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with tasks or multithreading - it's just that your lambda is capturing a variable, not a value.

Comment: @Stephen hit it. This should fix you up: `dim hij = ji` `Task.Run(Sub() findPageCount(hij)`

Comment: @StephenCleary,that worked, and I think I understand why. Is there something somewhere I could read though as I've not heard of a lambda before, but assume it's something to do with the new thread being created asynchronously?

Comment: @MartinKS: No, it has nothing to do with threads or asynchrony. You can read more [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2008/02/01/Capture-Variables-with-Closures.aspx).